# How can I cast MenuItem to ActionMenuItem in espresso?

Tags: android, android-espresso

```
onView(withId(com.help.R.id.menu_item)).check(matches(CustomMatchers.withActionIconDrawableNumberOflayers(2)));
```

Here I am using a Custom Matcher to check the number of layers on the menu item.

```
   public static Matcher<View> withActionIconDrawableNumberOflayers(final int numberOflayers) {
    return new BoundedMatcher<View, ActionMenuItemView>(ActionMenuItemView.class) {
        @Override
        public void describeTo(final Description description) {
            description.appendText("has image layers " + numberOflayers);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean matchesSafely(final ActionMenuItemView actionMenuItemView) {
            LayerDrawable icon1 = (LayerDrawable) actionMenuItemView.getItemData().getIcon();
            int i = icon1.getNumberOfLayers();
            return i==numberOfLayers;
        }
    };
}
```

However I am not able to get past this line

```
LayerDrawable icon1 = (LayerDrawable) actionMenuItemView.getItemData().getIcon();
```

How do I cast MenuItem (com.help.R.id.menu_item) to ActionMenuItemView so I can get the numberOfLayers of the drawable of the menu item?